# How to list Azure AD users who have never logged in via Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to use the Graph API to give me all users in my tenants who have never logged in. I have tried calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity eq null&$select=displayName,signInActivity,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName,id
```

but that did not work. According to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts , a blank property for signInActivity means the account was never used for a successful login. Here is an example output of a user who has never logged in:

```
{
            "displayName": "Abdulahi Wilder",
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "userPrincipalName": "abdulahit@8tvlg4.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "316777d5-eb5a-4e35-bd0d-3cc09eea2bf3"
        },
```

and this is a user who has had a successful login

```
 {
            "displayName": "Adele Vance",
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@8tvlg4.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "9484044e-5c56-4aae-bce0-ca9f87f45d6f",
            "signInActivity": {
                "lastSignInDateTime": "2022-05-20T02:44:11Z",
                "lastSignInRequestId": "3168e293-4519-4122-bf38-a10c433d0600",
                "lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "lastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId": ""
            }
```

I am having trouble understanding how I can call the API and list me the users with no signInActivity property. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

we can use this `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity&filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z` to filter out all the users who hasn't signed in since `2019-06-01`. And this is designed for getting inactive users in your tenant.

But it doesn't provide the ability to fitler the users who never signed in, since this is a known issue those uses won't return `signInActivity` property just like you showed in your question. Because this property doesn't return for those users, we can't do filter on `signInActivity` property.

[image]